# Apply.monthly on XTS to non-zero columns

Tags: r

Looking to use the apply.monthly function on a xts table which has multiple column. It works well for Max, but Mean and Min are affected by the fact that some column have zero as value. Can i apply this function without counting column with zero ?

```
apply.monthly(Total.Consumption.df, min)
```

Sorry if this is a very simple issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to replace the `0` with `NA` and then get the `min/max` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
apply.monthly(replace(Total.Consumption.df, Total.Consumption.df == 0, NA),
        min, na.rm = TRUE)
```